# NSURLRequest odd behaivor

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm having such an odd problem.  I'm running iOS 4.3.2 on my device.  Compiling in Xcode 4 but I am not using the iOS 5 beta SDK.

My app fetches a plist file from a server, the plist file is set of strings I use in my app.

I get the data via a request and connection like so

```
    NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pathAndFile]
                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSURLConnection *con =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req 
                                                      delegate:self];
```

When running on wifi - if I go up and make a change on the server side, the app will see the new data and use it each time the app is launched.

If I switch my phone over to 3G it goes and grabs the data correctly the FIRST TIME.  If I then go back and change the file on the server, and rerun the app - it is only loading the OLD data, not the new data.  The app IS hitting the code where the connection is established and loaded.

Ok, so now I'm in this state where the app is using old data.  I switch the phone to wifi and BAM, the new data is there.

But if I now close the app.  Turn off wifi.  Launch the app, the app is using the OLD DATA again.

I did implement

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse {
return nil;
```

}

as suggested in another stackoverflow thread.  Anybody have any thoughts why this could be happening and how I could make it work correctly?

Comment: There are many things that could do wrong here. A transparent proxy could be caching the file; either by your 3G provider, or your internet ISP.

Comment: I changed the code to point at my webhost rather than the Amazon S3 servers and the changes ALWAYS propagated through correctly regardless of connection type.  So either Amazon is doing some kind of odd caching or AT&T is.

Comment: I'd say AT&T; mobile carriers are known to squeeze every byte they can.

Answer (score 1):

I am just throwing this out there as something to check:

I have a hard time believing this but perhaps your 3G carrier is caching? Can you check your server logs to see if you are receiving the actual calls from the device? If not, try concatenating an random querystring value on the end of the URL on every request and then check the server logs again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My 3G carrier is AT&T.  The server is an amazon S3 server.